# Can't fill in the mnesia table

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I wrote this code snippet:

```
Player   = t:user(List),
CatchAll = [{'_', [], ['$_']}],
NameList = mnesia:dirty_select(player, CatchAll),
if
  (length(NameList) < 4)->
    T3 = fun() ->
             X3 = #player{name = Player},
             mnesia:write(X3)
         end,
    mnesia:transaction(T3),
    NameList1 = mnesia:dirty_select(player, CatchAll),
    ?INFO_MSG("1The value of NameList1 is ~p~n", [NameList1]),
    ok;
  (length(NameList) == 4)->
    ?INFO_MSG("2The value of NameList is ~p~n", [NameList])
end,
```

Here, each time a call a module t:user I get a name which i have stored in Player and want to keep storing these names till there are 4 of them but each i time I run this I get an empty value of Namelist as [], instead of a list filled with players name.

Any Idea on why this is happening?

Comment: I'm guessing the transaction is failing for some reason. I would suggest matching on the result of the transaction to make sure it succeeds, and crash with some details if it doesn't. i.e change 
    mnesia:transaction(T3)

to

    {atomic, _Result} = mnesia:transaction(T3)

Comment: @spawn_think first of all thank you for replying.Here's what I did. I saw that I have only one entry i.e "name" in the mnesia table. For some reason this was giving me error. what I did was i calculated the length of each player's name and stored it with his name and since then I am experiencing no problem at all as far as mnesia is concerned. But I didn't completely understand the reason behind this behaiviour of erlang(mnesia). If you do, then I would like to request you to please give it's explanation. It will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't get what you mean there. Where did you store the length of player's name and why do you need that? Also which error did you get before?
P.S: It would help if you explain in steps what you tried and which errors you got

Comment: earliar my record #player only had one entry I changed it to (player,{name,num}).Then I calculated the length of the name of each player (i.e length of Player) and then stored these respective lengths inside the num entry of the record player,and then i was able to fill the mnesia table without any problem.